# How do I initialize a bucket_list with dynamic data in R?

Tags: r, sortablejs

I would like to initialize a bucket_list in R with data from a dataframe. Let's assume I got the following data:

```
buckets <- data.frame(
  text=c("A","A","B"),
  labels=c(1,2,3)
)
```

Then I would like to achieve the following bucket_list:

```
library(sortable)
bucket_list(
  header="Test"
  ,add_rank_list(text = "A",labels = c(1,2))
  ,add_rank_list(text = "B",labels = c(1) )
)
```

My problem is that the contents of the dataframe *buckets* are dynamic, so I need a solution that takes the dataframe *buckets* as input.

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your data.frame to a grouped list. Then, use `lapply` for each group and `add_rank_list` to put each list element into format needed for `bucket_list`.

```
library(sortable)

buckets <- data.frame(
  text=c("A","A","B"),
  labels=c(1,2,3)
)

blst <- split(buckets$labels, buckets$text)

rlst <- lapply(names(blst), function(x) {
  add_rank_list(
    text = x,
    label = blst[[x]]
  )
})

do.call(bucket_list, c(header = "New Test Here", rlst))
```